# Matrix Columns plot in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, matrix, charts, data-visualization

I have a matrix whose dimensions are unknown until the code executes. It could be any size. I want to plot the points using different colours for each column.
Say column 1 uses one colour, column 2 uses another colour, and so on.

I have this code, but it plots all the points with the same colour. Any ideas?

```
Dim s1 As New System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series

s1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point
s1.Name = "Clusters"

For h = 1 To Num_clusters 'number of columns

    For ss = 1 To jobs 'maximum row size

        If clusters(ss, h) <> 0 Then 'depending of code execution, it could be rows empty, so checking only non-empty rows

            s1.Points.AddXY(x(clusters(ss, h)), y(clusters(ss, h))) 'Just taking the X-Y components of the data
            s1.Color = Color.FromArgb(h + 100, 162, 178) 'Here trying to make all columns different colours with the h+100 (h=column index)
        End If
    Next  'Row

    'after reading the rows from this column, add the points with a colour
    'Chart1.Series.Add(s1)    'If I run this here an error happens and it doesn't plot 
Next  'Column

'If I add chart series here would plot all with the same colour
```

I was thinking if the first loop h something like this

```
For h = 1 To Num_clusters 'number of columns
    Dim (s & h) As New Series 'Trying to automatically create new series:     s1,s2,...,sNum_clusters
    For ss = 1 To jobs 'maximum row size
        'code
        '
        '
        '
     Next 'rows
'Chart1.Series.Add(s & h) 
Next 'column
```

But I don't know what the correct syntax to auto create new series `s` and `h` would be.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You are adding all of the points to just one series. I think you need to create a different series for each column. The each series can be assigned a different color.

Comment: yea That is what I thought, but I couldn't find a way to define unlimited series. But I already solved it using s1.Points(jj).Color and putting some conditional to the jj counter